# Fastest way to get data from my table on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I really need your help with my problem.

I have a table called **member_histories** it contains 5+ million data so my query takes a very long time and the page is not loading properly.

Here my query:

```
public function scopeAllPurchases()
{
    return $this->model
        ->whereIn('member_histories.action', [MemberHistoryAction::BUY, MemberHistoryAction::SUBSCRIBE])
        ->leftJoin('members', 'members.id', '=', 'member_histories.member_id');
}
```

How can I improve this query? Does anyone have an idea? I used Laravel framework.

Comment: Have you indexed your tables?

Comment: As already suggested, first check your indicies.  `where in` can be slow in SQL, if you only have 2 options, try testing if (pseudo-code) `where action=buy OR where action=subscribe` is faster.